# Terminal still shows older version of rails even after updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a beginner in web development and following the book, Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. I updated my rails using command `gem install rails -v 3.2.3` and it seemed to work. But when I checked the rails version using command `rails -v`, it still shows some different version: `Rails 4.2.5.2`. I restarted my terminal but no luck. Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: rvm is already installed. Can you tell me exact command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because there are now two versions of `rails` in your `railties`.
Try to run this first:

```
gem uninstall railties
```

By running this command your screen will show rails gems list like the following:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
1. railties-3.2.18
2. railties-4.2.6
3. All versions
>
```

Type 3 to remove all. now your gem list has no `rails` gem. Now you can install `rails -v 3.2.3`. After installation, `rails -v` will show: `Rails 3.2.3`

Comment: Thanks you so much @Ahasan. It worked perfect. I can't accept your answer as I dont have required repo. What if I install same version twice? Will it overwrite original files?

Comment: I am glad, this helped you.
Yes, it will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall Rails, you can use:

```
gem uninstall -a rails
```

This command uninstalls all (-a) gems matching 'rails.' You can then install your desired version of rails.

Check out [this documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/) with a full list of gem commands.

If you're using RVM and you just want to nuke your entire gem ecosystem and rebuild from scratch, you can go to your home directory, find the `.rvm` directory and `rm -R` the `gems` directory.

The whole point of RVM, however, is that it lets you manage different versions of gems. You can build a gemset with Rails 4.x and a different gemset with Rails 3.x and switch between the versions at will. See [RVM documentation](https://rvm.io/gemsets/using) for more information on building and using gemsets.

Just as an added note, you might want to keep Rails 4.x and get rid of the older version. I realize your tutorial uses the older version, but Rails 5 is already out, and there's no reason to start your Rails experience in a technological hole. As I recall, the Hartl tutorial is largely usable with Rails 4 with few, if any, issues.